# Software parallelization with OpenMP versus Affinity scheduling?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, affinity

Scenario: I have an program which can be *easily* parallelized using OpenMP, lets say the main loop of the program is a for loop and independent data within it, so paralleizing it would be trivial. However currently I **don't** parallelize it, and instead use affinity scheduling.

This program performs work on some input files specified by a folder in the command line arguments. To run this program in parallel, someone can create a bat file like so:

```
start \affinity 1 "1" bat1
start \affinity 2 "2" bat2
start \affinity 3 "3" bat3
start \affinity 4 "4" bat4
```

where bat1 - 4 is a bat file that calls `main.exe` with a different input folder for each bat file. So in this case there would be 4 instances of `main.exe` running on `input_folder1, input_folder2, input_folder3, input_folder4` respectively.

**What would be the benefits of using a library like OpenMP be instead of affinity scheduling**? I figure

- Less memory usage, single stack and heap for a single program instance as opposed to `n` instances of a program for `n` cores
- Better scaling

But would I expect to actually see a performance boost? Why if so?

Comment: How about the benefit that the user does not have to create a huge bat file every time it has to be run in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is a simply parallel, with no interaction among the data in the separate input files, then you would probably not see a speedup with OpenMP, and might even see a slow-down, since memory allocation and various other things then have to be thread-safe. Single-threaded processes can gain lots of efficiencies, and in fact do on GNU libc, where linking in POSIX threads support means you also get a slower implementation of `malloc`

Comment: That last statement about `malloc` is interesting. Could you please provide some pointers to the glibc source code or the documentation to back it? I don't see `malloc` coming in different versions in glibc 2.12 or newer although ptmalloc2 could be compiled without thread safety. Besides, the library has the option to create one memory arena per core for (almost) lock-free implementation of `malloc` and at least RedHat-based distributions come with that option turned on.

Comment: This is from memory, but my recollection is that linking with `-lpthread` got a different version or perhaps build configuration of malloc interposed.